# Why doesn't anyone use reinforcement learning to find the best possible alternative to backpropagation?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation, hyperparameter-optimization, meta-learning

To be clear, I'm very uninformed on the topic of alternative learning algorithms to backprop, all my knowledge comes from articles like these:
[lets-not-stop-at-backprop](https://analyticsindiamag.com/lets-not-stop-at-back-prop-check-out-5-alternatives-to-this-popular-deep-learning-technique/)
[backprop-alternatives](https://medium.com/@sallyrobotics.blog/backpropagation-and-its-alternatives-c09d306aae4c)
[we-need-a-better-learning-algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-we-need-a-better-learning-algorithm-than-backpropagation-in-deep-learning-2faa0e81f6b). I also don't know exactly how you would arrange a system to find the best learning algorithm it can, or if it's even possible to make something like that with reinforcement learning.

I was thinking that you could take a system and have it generate neural nets in the space of all neural nets and generate rules for how to deal with the weights in the network, and then just let the system run trying to find the best possible arrangement of neurons and training rules such that it can learn how to do x thing very very fast, with very little training.

Is this something that has already been tried or something that isn't possible?